# Create links from file name from folder

Tags: php

Iam writting here for the first time. I wrote some php code which read files from folder and makes list of links to each file. Problem is that, its generates two more links at the begining of the list, which arent links to files, only dots. Does anyone have some idea to help me about this? This is the code:

```
 <?php
echo '<h1>Download</h1>';
echo '<br/>';
echo '<div id="download">';
$dir = "images/download/";


if (is_dir($dir)) {

  if($dh = opendir($dir)) {
    while(($file = readdir($dh))!==false){

      echo '<a href="'.$dir.urlencode($file).'">'. str_replace("_"," ", trim($file,'.pdf, .pptx')) . "</a>";

    }
    closedir($dh);

  }
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You always have to check for the `.` and `..` directories and ignore them. They exist in every folder.

They are what are used when you do `cd ..` and `ls .` for example in a command window

```
<?php
echo '<h1>Download</h1>';
echo '<br/>';
echo '<div id="download">';
$dir = "images/download/";


if (is_dir($dir)) {

    if($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while(($file = readdir($dh))!==false){

            if ( $file == '.' || $file == '..' ) {
                continue;
            }

            echo '<a href="'.$dir.urlencode($file).'">'. str_replace("_"," ", trim($file,'.pdf, .pptx')) . "</a>";

        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
    echo '</div>';
?>
```